# how to use ngroute with radio buttons being used to changed the view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute

Now i have written a code to change the view of the page using ng-route. The code is

```
<a href="#cod">Cash on delivery</a>
<a href="#online">Online Payment</a>
<ng-view>
</ng-view>
```

And the js code is

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/cod', {
        templateUrl: './cod.html',
        controller:'codController'
    }).
      when('/online', {
        templateUrl: './online.html',
        controller:'onlineController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/cartdisplay.php'
      });
}]);
```

It is working fine the views are changing properly.
But I need the radio buttons to change the view like

```
 <a href="#cod">
     <input type="radio" name="pay" id="cod">
     <label for="cod">COD</label>
 </a>
 <a href="#online">
     <input type="radio" name="pay" id="online">
     <label for="online">Online Payment</label>
 </a>
 <ng-view>
 </ng-view>
```

But now the views are not changing. ngRoute isnt working,
What is the solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have cod and online as routes?

Comment: try $location.path('/newValue') in ur ng-change event of radio button.

Comment: Try `href='#/cod'` and `href='#/online'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="pay" id="cod" ng-model="someVariableOfScope"><label for="cod" data-ng-click="changeRoute('cod')">COD</label>
    <input type="radio" name="pay" id="online" data-ng-click="changeRoute('online')"><label for="online" ng-model="someVariableOfScope ">Online Payment</label>
             <ng-view>
         </ng-view>
```

In your controller:

```
    function SomeCommonController($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
     $scope.changeRoute = function(routeKey) {
       if ( $scope.routeKey == 'cod' ) { // test

            $location.path( "/cod" );
        } else ( $scope.routeKey == 'online' ) { {
                    $location.path( "/online" );
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is working. The views are changing but my radio buttons are not being selected. i.e It is not being highlighted with the black dot.

Comment: I have edited the answer that should work now. Added ng-model to the radio controls